# Converting GSize pixels to LatLngBounds for static image

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In the Google Maps API v2 I placed a 125 x 130 pixel png image on my map with GSize(125,130) using the 3rd party EInsert.

API v3 provides the native groundOverlay using an imageBounds object.

OK, I got that to work, and by guessing the LatLngBounds I get pretty close, but would prefer to know how to convert the pixels of my image to degrees so my image would render at 100% with the correct aspect ratio.

I'm not trying to do any fancy resizing or dynamic calculation.

I just want to know **1 pixel = x degrees** [near (37,-122) and at zoom level 10]